# Mails sent from GAE go in the spam folder of hotmail even after editing SPF record

Tags: google-app-engine

Just wondering if someone else found a solution to the following :

--> I have an application running on GAE sending emails

--> These emails are delivered with no problem to gmail accounts but arrive in the spam folder of hotmail

--> I have adapted the SPF record in the nameserver to "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all" but that did not help

There are a few discussions on this subject in the past but not clear on whether or not there is another solution than asking people to add the application email in the contact list.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also add [DKIM](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174124) now that [AppEngine finally supports it](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3161).

Comment: Shay, just to let you know that you were right. I'll add a note in this post to explain in detail how to solve it for other people if they face the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is having the same issue.

**Problem description**

Mail sent from Google App Engine are delivered correctly to gmail.com but arrive in the spam folder of hotmail.com and are even automatically deleted from other

**Solution**

Two steps to follow:

1. In the SPF record in the nameserver, include "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
2. If you email accounts are managed by Google Apps, [follow the DKIM procedure](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174124). This involves adding TXT records in your nameserver. Some companies offer to update this on-line, I add to exchange emails with the support of my registrar.