# Email from Google App Engine goes in the SPAM folder even after following the DKIM procedure

Tags: google-app-engine

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774590/mails-sent-from-gae-go-in-the-spam-folder-of-hotmail-even-after-editing-spf-reco/11793615#11793615), I was wondering if someone had also emails from Google App Engine ending up in the spam folder of Hotmail.

Thanks to help from the community, I could find a way to solve the issue. I did leave the original post as it solves the issue for a set of email systems (such as free.fr).

However, the fix was unfortunately partial and it remains issues with hotmail. Once this problem will be solved, I will update the initial post.

You'll find below the message which ends up in the spam folder of Hotmail.

What looks weird to me is the following :

- Yesterday I made tests where the email had "dkim=pass". Today other tests have "dkim=temperror". Although yesterday I had "dkim=pass", the messages ended up in the spam folder
- Today I have "dkim=temperror" and I don't understand what it means

Does anyone has some ideas ? Getting more and more difficult to understand why it works on all email systems except hotmail.

Thanks,

Hugues

x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR3P+ctWZsO+J
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=pass (sender IP is 209.85.213.207) header.from=admin@plugsystems.com; **dkim=temperror** header.d=plugsystems.com; x-hmca=pass
X-SID-PRA: admin@plugsystems.com
X-Message-Status: n:0:n
X-SID-Result: Pass
X-DKIM-Result: TempError
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: o9rlR4nWDTdAvwKKkW+ebjaNRBhWfirkKplRTvFb0jLyKfWDD1CiQJSrYGPEuh2GOIiEGly1AGxiI/aHFqM5d3PpaLYYerrWHzwUPlyoEy9CbytLpScTK1Jq+2/GQW4lIqYx3o3TG40EkcgVaBPqlw==
Received: from mail-yx0-f207.google.com ([209.85.213.207]) by BAY0-MC3-F27.Bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Sat, 4 Aug 2012 03:55:31 -0700
Received: by yenl5 with SMTP id l5so28780yen.6
        for ; Sat, 04 Aug 2012 03:55:31 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=plugsystems.com; s=google;
        h=mime-version:reply-to:x-google-appengine-app-id:message-id:date
         :subject:from:to:content-type:content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=euOvGlAMboKg1Q3U9r2HjPZ7pOICyqvz1yxwQnTnDp8=;
        b=VLAlR0aAgxPJ/a3E+ZgWuZWXb3ZgocGXCPcp/4B0mLeCnI02mmohF6TLm2wMj1O8Od
         HW8H6EIujSK/oirDJSAyyqN5/u1vhL3Bs0B2lafJjBVDkSsL1mP7DBIj6HMKrQpd6cee
         b+URUbQ0tT8cadBoilvBxklEbt6d2XKFl5qBw=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.236.116.74 with SMTP id f50mr2524543yhh.33.1344077731015; Sat,
 04 Aug 2012 03:55:31 -0700 (PDT)
Reply-To: Plugimmo 
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id: s~plugimmo
Message-ID: <20cf303dd262b52b2404c66e7b3a@google.com>
Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2012 10:55:31 +0000
Subject: Plugimmo
From: Plugimmo 
To: Olivier Truemath 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Return-Path: 3o_8cUAgJEJwLHQCEIIKCI6EH.8KIKHEREAN.PNQAI6PDDKPI6EH.BN@M3KW2WVRGUFZ5GODRSRYTGD7.apphosting.bounces.google.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Aug 2012 10:55:31.0611 (UTC) FILETIME=[AAAD0EB0:01CD722F]

Qm9uam91ciwNCkxlIGJ1dCBkZSBjZXQgZW1haWwgZXN0IGRlIHbpcmlmaWVyIHF1ZSB2b3VzIGF2
ZXogZWZmZWN0aXZlbWVudCBkZW1hbmTpICANCmFjY+hzIGF1IHNlcnZpY2UgUGx1Z2ltbW8gcG91
ciBsJ2VtYWlsIDogb2xpdmllci50cnVlbWF0aEBob3RtYWlsLmZyDQpTaSB2b3VzIGF2ZXogZWZm
ZWN0aXZlbWVudCBkZW1hbmTpIGFjY+hzIGF1IHNlcnZpY2UgcGx1Z2ltbW8sIHZldWlsbGV6ICAN
CmNsaXF1ZXIgc3VyIGxlIGxpZW4gY2ktZGVzc291cyBwb3VyIGNvbmZpcm1lciB2b3RyZSBkZW1h
bmRlDQpodHRwOi8vcGx1Z2ltbW8uYXBwc3BvdC5jb20vcGx1Z2ltbW8vdmVyaWZ5RW1haWw/Y29k
ZT03MjJjNGFhM2NhYTlhNWZlNTIzZTVjZDU3OTQxZjdlOA0K

Comment: Did you ever find a solution of this?

Comment: Did anyone ever get this working? I've implemented SPF, Sender-ID and DKIM, all being reported as PASS on the email source that arrives on Hotmail, but it's still being marked as Junk. :(

Comment: Hi Ricardo. I still have randomly emails being sent to the spam folder of Hotmail. My only hope is that over time as more and more people classify my mails not as spam, Hotmail will classify emails from my web site as trustworthy. This is really a pain and I just don't understand why Microsoft is not doing something about it.

Comment: @RicardoCabral, I've updated answer to include additional information and tools from Microsoft that'll help you discover why your mail is going to spam. Hopefully it helps you, best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the DKIM temperror but take a look at  step 3. "Set up a SenderID record" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html.
I think hotmail in particular uses SenderID, which may be the cause of your mails going to spam.

Also take a look http://mailchimp.com/about/authentication/ which shows a breakdown of which mail servers use each type of authentication.

Good luck,
Rob

**Edit:**

If you are still having issues with mail going to the junkmail in Hotmail, then have a look at [this resource](https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsjmrpp&ct=eformts&scrx=1) from Microsoft. The resource provides a suite of services to help you find out why your mail is being spammed, and tools to help you stop your mails going to spam.

Summary of the links on include:

- [Joining the junk email reporting program to receive updates about your mails that gets spammed](https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsjmrpp&ct=eformts)
- [Joining Smart Sender Service to see how ip-range,mails etc are rated/viewed by Hotmail filters](http://postmaster.live.com/snds)
- [Deliverability Issue Submission](https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl2&ct=eformts)
- [Third party service to safelist senders](http://g.live.com/9wc9en-us/senderscore)